# Consider rows unique when a given column matches predicate in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

In the context of a uniqueness constraint, is there a way to consider rows unique if a given column has a specific value, for example "false".

As an example,

this would be allowed:

```
id  | user| location| active
----+-----+----------+----------
  1 |   1 | West LA  | f
  2 |   1 | West LA  | f
  3 |   1 | West LA  | t
  4 |   2 | West LA  | t
```

but this would not:

```
id  | user| location| active
----+-----+----------+----------
  1 |   1 | West LA  | f
  2 |   1 | West LA  | t
  3 |   1 | West LA  | t
  4 |   2 | West LA  | t
```

To achieve this, I would like to know if it is possible to make a uniqueness constraint similar to this:
`UNIQUE(user, location)`

but only apply it `WHERE active = true`

Comment: would you please provide sample of data that could coexist and sample of row that would give an exception?..

Comment: @VaoTsun no problem!  hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: yes - thank you. I still dont get the origin of day, but you probably just dont list all columns?.. anyway you have answer already.

Comment: @VaoTsun sorry, i made a mistake in copying when i changed it a bit.  you're right i took out several columns for the example.  corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there - create a partial (aka "filtered") unique index:

```
create unique index on the_table (day, location) 
   where active;
```